# Netlify renders 404 on page refresh (using React and react-router)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404, netlify

I have deployed my site with Netlify, and I’m having trouble with the routing.

Here is my website: https://redux-co.netlify.com/

And my GitHub repo: https://github.com/jenna-m/redux-co

Specifically, if a user navigates to any page besides the home page and refreshes the page, the default Netlify 404 renders. From the 404 page, if I navigate back to the home page and refresh, the home page is rendered.

Also, my custom 404 page isn’t working as it does when I’m on `localhost:3000`, but I would like to get this refresh issue figured out first before dealing with my custom 404 component.

I’m using React and react-router, and I understand that since I’m using react-router, my website won’t deploy right out of the box.

---

This is my `_redirects` file, which is in the `/public` folder with  my `index.html` file:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

This is my `“build”` located in `package.json`:

```
…
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && cp build/index.html build/404.html",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
…
```

---

I have read about other people experiencing this and what they’ve done to overcome the problem. This is what I’ve referenced so far…

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-to-netlify-363b8a98a985/

https://hugogiraudel.com/2017/05/13/using-create-react-app-on-netlify/

This person was using Vue and not React, but I gave these solutions an attempt anyway:

https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/457#issuecomment-390206649

https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/457#issuecomment-463745656

Comment: hm, strange. Maybe you have set something wrong on Netlify settings

Answer (score 170, accepted):

**This was simple and it worked for me**. I found this link https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#netlify

So as suggested by that link, I added a `_redirects` file inside the `/public` folder like `/public/_redirects`. I then pasted `/*  /index.html  200` into the `_redirects` file. I did all that in my VS Code, after which I pushed to github and then ofcourse my  netlify re-deploys automatically everytime I push to github. My problem was solved and **refresh nolonger brings the 404 error.**

In my package.json, the build section looks like this;

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

**Note:**
Some articles say that you need to add `_redirects` in the `build` folder, but then build folder is not among what gets pushed to github in my case, so that's why adding `_redirects` to `public` folder worked better for me, as the public folder can be pushed along with my code.

Comment: Hi this did help me while deploying my static site on NETLIFY, but when I tried same thing on RENDER platform, this hack didn't help. Any idea how to fix the same issue while deploying my static site on Render ?

Comment: @user14106566 Glad to know the hack helped when working with netlify. Unfortunately, I haven't worked with the Render platform and I am not able to tell why the hack wouldn't work.

Comment: no worries at all,  cause I have figured out a similar workaround with render deployment as well. While deploying your  site, you just need to tweak the settings. Under settings there is a redirect tab, just edit it the same way like this _redirects file.

Comment: I used this same solution to fix my react-router site on Netlify, but now the Google Search Console is listing some of those pages with a "Soft 404" and declaring them non-indexable by Google. Has anyone seen this before? It could just be a temporary transition issue from my old site, but if not I want to fix it ASAP.

Comment: @TimHayes I haven't encountered that. Would be nice to let us know when you get a workaround.

Answer (score 90):

Add `netlify.toml` file to the root directory of your project and paste the following code in it:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/"
  status = 200
```

push and redeploy your app and it's done.

Comment: +1 Accessing my react-app routes, such as /contact on netlify directly via URL (not via app UI) triggered 404. This file solved it.

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked for me. I first tried `_redirects` in `\public` directory but it was not worked.

Answer (score 15):

Remove `_redirects` from your public folder and move `netlify.toml` to the root of your git repo, [more info](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#structured-configuration).   Also remove from build script `&& cp build/index.html build/404.html` - you don't need that any more

Comment: Works like a charm! After implementing your solution, I also got my custom 404 pages to work. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: I added this in netlify.toml and it works!
`[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200`

Comment: can you explain why `_redirects` is the wrong answer given its the accepted answer with 8x ups?

Comment: @notacorn no one said that _redirects is the wrong answer

Comment: well, you said to remove it?

Comment: that's because repo already has netlify.toml with `[[redirects]]` section and in that case we don't need `_redirects` file anymore

Comment: @nico Hi this did help me while deploying my static site on NETLIFY, but when I tried same thing on RENDER platform, this hack didn't help. Any idea how to fix the same issue while deploying my static site on Render ?

Answer (score 11):

I was having a similar issue
so I created **_redirects** file in the public folder and put the following code

```
/* /index.html 200
```

build files again **npm run build**
and worked for me
[resource for similar issue](https://dev.to/rajeshroyal/page-not-found-error-on-netlify-reactjs-react-router-solved-43oa)

Answer (score 4):

If you ran into this issue for React Native Web, using an Expo-managed workflow, this solution fixed the problem:

1. Create a **netlify.toml** in the project's root directory.
2. Add the following code in the **netlify.toml** file:

```
    [[redirects]]
    from = "/*"
    to = "/index.html"
    status = 200
```

3. Run the `netlify deploy` command in your terminal.

Answer (score 4):

This is my _redirects file, which is in the /public folder with my index.html file:

_redirects in

/*    /index.html   200

and then re-deploy your site in Netlify.

Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same refresh issue in netlify. For me it was a series of changes. I had before my react configuration pointing to a subfolder `(/sandbox/appfolder)` to use in my hosting sandbox (I hope I can revert to that changing the parameters below). To be able to do a continuous deploy in netlify I did the following inspired in other answers. When using my own hosting sandbox, I didn't have the _redirects and the homepage pointed to the subfolder.

EDIT: to run from my site's subfolder I had to edit .htaccess to `RewriteRule ^ /sandbox/myapp/index.html [L]` and package.json to `"homepage": "/sandbox/myapp"`

in /package.json:

```
"homepage": "/",
```

in /public/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Fallback all other routes to index.html    
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

in my main component src/App.js:

```
<BrowserRouter basename = {process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
```

in public/index.html

```
<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">
```

and finally as mentioned in /public/_redirects

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Answer (score 3):

2022 Update:

> If **adding _redirects file did not work for me**.(React JS)

For me the solution was to create **netlify.toml** file in the base directory of my react project. Then adding following.

`[[redirects]] from = "/*" to = "/" status = 200`

Answer (score 3):

For me worked the next solution.
First of all create a file on your **public** folder named **_redirects** (no extension, just pure text) and type -> `/* /index.html 200` in it. Then in your **package.json** file set at very top the property `{ homepage: "YOUR PUBLIC URL", ...rest of the properties }` and in the **index.html** file add `<head>...<base href="YOUR PUBLIC URL">...</head>`.
Got the answer from [this blog post](https://answers.netlify.com/t/the-stylesheet-was-not-loaded-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-text-css/36336/8), user called **hrishikesh**.

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`Using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter solves the problem

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
//instead of 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Answer (score 1):

create **_redirects** in the root directory
mention your app routes inside the **_redirects** file, for example:
/home
/terms-and-condition

that's it.

Comment: could you add how to mention app routes inside the _redirects file?

Comment: Either in the Root or Public folder create a file named "_redirects" and add the following text: `/*  /index.html  200`

Answer (score 1):

### try this

faced this same issue previously, founded that it was because of the proxy that I was using to connect to my backend server. Let's say the backend app is located at this URL example.com. So, instead of mentioning this as a proxy field in package.json, I would suggest putting the link in your functions only.

#### avoid this

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "https://example.com",
  "private": true,
....
....
}
```

If, using redux then in put your backend url in actions with axios or fetch. (Also, try deleting the package-lock.json file and then push the code without it on your Github and then connect it to netifly and then re-deploy your site)

#### Example code (notice api call)

```
export const listArticles = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: ARTICLES_LIST_REQUEST
        })

        // api call
        const { data } = await axios.get("https://example.com/api/articles/")

        dispatch({
            type: ARTICLES_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: ARTICLES_LIST_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail ? error.response.data.detail : error.message
        })
    }
}
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "mdbreact": "^5.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I added the `_redirects` file and that did not work. I played with my CI settings again and in my build command I wrote `CI = npm run build` but then in the Public Directory field I wrote `build` and then triggered a redeploy and my site finally worked!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the `_redirects` file and the `netlify.toml` updates but was still getting the 404. For me, the fix was to update the `Build Settings` on `netlify.com`. I think changing the `Publish Directory` to `./build` was the fix:

[image: netlify build settings]

By the way, I followed some suggestions on stack/elsewhere to add a tag in my `index.html` file, and also to update the `homepage` in my `package.json`. Neither of these things helped and may have also messed up my fetch requests. (just in case anyone else was having similar issues)

Answer (score 0):

Add a netlify.toml file in the root folder with the contents:

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/"
status = 200
```

and it will work.

[image: netlify.toml contents]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `/public folder`.
2. Create file called `_redirects`.
3. Add the following code into the file: `/* /index.html 200`.
4. Publish your app again. It should fix the Netlify **page not found error**.

Answer (score -1):

create-react-app documentation for deployment on Netlify mentioned to add _redirect file to avoid such issues:

**Support for client-side routing:**

To support `pushState` make sure to create a `public/redirects` file with the following rewrite rules:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

When you build the project, Create React App will place the `public` folder contents into the build ouput.

Reference:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify

Comment: Do not include pictures of text in your posts, it is not helpful. Text is text: type it out.

Answer (score -4):

From your index.js, just wrap your component with HashRouter instead of whatever that's there earlier.
Don't forget to import HashRouter from react-router-dom.

It's magical.