# React - Doesn't work refreshing page on react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify, reach-router

I am building front-end of marketplace using react.
"react": "^17.0.2"
"react-redux": "^7.2.5"
"react-scripts": "4.0.3"
@reach/router": "^1.3.4"

**After built the app on local or netlify, when refreshing page(F5), it doesn't work and it returns blank page.
In details, "404: The requested path could not be found" on local, and then blank page with console error on netlify.**

But, it does work well on local dev(yarn start) and from clicking menu after built.

I had already tried to add *"homepage":"."* on package.json and *_redirects* file with */* /index.html 200* on root and build folder.

I am not sure whether it is build setting problem or @reach/router issue.

How can I fix this issue?

Hope to your quick help.

Thank you,

PS: Attached my issue screenshots.

[Error on local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84cdn.png)

[Error on netlify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6hWi.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Netlify renders 404 on page refresh (using React and react-router)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065603/netlify-renders-404-on-page-refresh-using-react-and-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

create a **.htaccess** file in the public directory of your react project and paste the text below.

```htaccess
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

When built again and re-uploaded it should not have an error on reload.

Comment: Tried as your mention, but, still same error

Comment: maybe this'll fix your problem... [How to fix Page Not Found on netlify](https://dev.to/kapi1/how-to-fix-page-not-found-on-netlify-a4i)

Comment: Already added _redirects file before your advice. it doesn't work.